# Inspect a var ResultSet using NetBeans 12.5

Tags: java, database, variables, netbeans, resultset

How can I inspect my Java resultset variable in NetBeans? When I put the variable into a watcher there is a tree of content, but where can I find the data which was retrieved from the database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> where can I find the data which was retrieved from the database?

The easiest solution for you would be to print out the result set ...
This can be done like this.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
        int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
        System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID + ", " + price +
                           ", " + sales + ", " + total);
```

Here's how the [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) class works and how it can be used.